# How to implement search function on images without a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi I am trying to write a code that will allow the user to search a book name and make only that book with that specific name appear. But for some reason the search function doesn't work

This is my code so far:

```js
      var search = $("#search-criteria");
  var items  = $(".image-wrap");

  $("#search").on("click", function(e){

       var v = search.val().toLowerCase();
      if(v == "") {
          items.show();
          return;
      }
       $.each(items, function(){
           var it = $(this);
           var lb = it.find("id").text().toLowerCase();
           console.log( lb + " --- " + v);
           if(lb.indexOf(v) == -1)
                it.hide();
       });
   });
});
```

```css
  .review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 160px; // height
  //width: 30%; // width
  }
```

```html
    <form>
          <div> <input type="text" id="search-criteria" id="searchText"/>
    <input type="button" id="search" value="search" onClick="tes();"/> </div>
         </form>

    <section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img>    
<img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes to be done as part of the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).on("click","#search",function(e){
           var search = $("#search-criteria");
           var items  = $(".review-img");
           var v = search.val().toLowerCase();
           if(v == "") {
              items.show();
              return;
           }
           $.each(items, function(){
               var it = $(this);
               var lb = it.attr("id").toLowerCase();
               console.log( lb + " --- " + v);
               if(lb===v)
                    it.show();
                else
                    it.hide();
           });

      });
    </script>
```

This should work fine. Also remove onClick from the input button as we are going to perform search based on id of the button.

Please ask me if you need any other clarifications on this code

Comment: The code works but suppose I just type in life in the search it should still come up with life of pi

Comment: Another example is if I type in just in L it should come up with life of pi as well because it starts with L

Comment: If you want to check starting letter then you can replace lb===v with lb.startsWith(v). If you want to check if search term is anywhere in image then use lb.indexOf(v)!=-1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this is working fine for you. Please accept this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you review this line:

```
var lb = it.find("id").text().toLowerCase();
```

Take a look at what [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) does---`find("id")` doesn't give you the id of each element.

Comment: but it wouldn't make sense if I wrote something like #lifeofpi instead

Comment: the ID of an element is an attribute, not a descendant

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<datalist>` element with `.value` of child `<option>` elements set to each `.image img` `id`; `list` attribute at `#search-criteria` element set to `id` of `<datalist>` element. Call `.hide()` of `.images img` elements. At `click` at `#search` call `.show()` on `.value` of `#search-criteria`.

Note, `<img>` tag is self-closing.

```js
$(".images img").each(function() {
  $("#images").append(new Option(this.id, this.id));
}).hide();

$("#search").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".images img").hide()
  .filter("#" + $("#search-criteria").val())
  .show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <div> <input type="text" id="search-criteria" id="searchText" list="images" />
    <input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
    <datalist id="images"></datalist>
  </div>
</form>

<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi">
  <img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner">
  <img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars">
  <img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight">
</section>
```